# i was coding in manim and I got this error: getter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: manim

`
from manim import *

class ParabolaWithRiemannRectangles(Scene):
def construct(self):
# Create a coordinate system
plane = NumberPlane(
x_range=(-4, 4, 1),
y_range=(-1, 9, 1),
x_length=8,
y_length=10,
)

```
    # Define the parabola function
    def parabola(x):
        return x ** 2

    # Create the parabola graph
    parab_graph = plane.get_graph(parabola).set_color(GREEN)

    # Get Riemann rectangles for the parabola
    rectangles = plane.get_riemann_rectangles(
        parab_graph, x_range=(-4, 4), dx=0.5
    )

    # Add the coordinate system, parabola, and rectangles to the scene
    self.play(Create(plane))
    self.play(Create(parab_graph))
    self.play(Create(rectangles))
    self.wait()
```

`
TypeError: getter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 0):

`from manim import *`
indicates that you are using ManimCE, the community edition of Manim. However the command `.get_graph()` has in this edition of Manim a long time ago been replaced by `.plot()`

[Why are there different versions of Manim?](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/installation.html#why-are-there-different-versions-of-manim)
[Where can I find more resources for learning Manim?](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/general.html?highlight=discord#where-can-i-find-more-resources-for-learning-manim)

```py
from manim import *

class ParabolaWithRiemannRectangles(Scene): 
    def construct(self): 
        # Create a coordinate system 
        plane = NumberPlane( x_range=(-4, 4, 1), y_range=(-1, 9, 1), x_length=8, y_length=10, )

        # Define the parabola function
        def parabola(x):
            return x ** 2

        # Create the parabola graph
        parab_graph = plane.plot(parabola).set_color(GREEN)

        # Get Riemann rectangles for the parabola
        rectangles = plane.get_riemann_rectangles(
            parab_graph, x_range=(-4, 4), dx=0.5
        )

        # Add the coordinate system, parabola, and rectangles to the scene
        self.play(Create(plane))
        self.play(Create(parab_graph))
        self.play(Create(rectangles))
        self.wait()
```

[image: rendered result]